# How to get UIImageView size after autolayout is applied?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My storyboard has UIImageView which is automatically positioned and scaled by autolayout constraints.

When application runs, this UIImageView is properly resized and positioned according to device screen size and autolayout constraints.

How I can get UIImageView frame **after** it is displayed on the screen?
Common UIImageView.bounds and UIImageView.frame values return **original** values which were used in storyboard and does not reflect new UIImageView size.

Comment: Where did you put the code that gets the `frame`?

Comment: In - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated of main ViewController.

Comment: Great question, tbaranes's answer really helped me out. You should update the question to include the word "frame" as well as "size", so people trying to find out how to get the correct origin after constraints are applied can find this question as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to get the right frame/bounds of your `UIImageView` after resizing, you need first ask auto-layout to update that layout using `[yourImageView layoutIfNeeded]`. that will solve your constraints and update your `yourImage.bounds`.

```
[myImageView layoutIfNeeded];
NSLog(@"w: %f, h: %f", myImageView.bounds.size.width, myImageView.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your comment solved my question.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working for different size classes.

Comment: What if I want to animate that layout change and at the same time know the end frames after animation?

Comment: It seems `frame` is the right way to go, since `bounds` just return 0 for origin.

Answer (score 8):

Check these methods:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
// view is about to be added to hieararchy
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
// view was added
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
// VC just laid off its views
}
```

Comment: Yes, - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews is the proper place to get updated dimensions and also solved the propblem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kibernetik, don't forget to call **super**!

Comment: This is right place to do this. Make sure to use `frame` and not `bounds`.

Comment: @thedp: for height and width it doesn't matter