# Issues with corner radius

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
class CourseItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var label: UILabel!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        var frame = imageView.frame
        frame.size.height = 120
        frame.size.width = 212
        frame.origin.x = 0
        frame.origin.y = 0
        imageView.frame = frame
    
        imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

Unfortunately, corner radius is not working on the image view. What happens is that the top upper edges of the image look rectangular, while the bottom looks circular. It works for the bottom but not for the top. What I'm I doing wrong?

Update I tried:

```
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: .zero)
      setupViews()
      setupLayouts()
}

private func setupViews() {
    contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
    contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.setRoundedEdge(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 8)
    
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    contentView.addSubview(label)
}


extension UIImageView {
    func setRoundedEdge(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Before I see

[image]

Now I see

[image]

Note images are loaded via URL.

Comment: for the updated part, when you calling the setRoundedEdge, the bounds of the imageView is (0, 0, 0, 0) and thats why the image disappear.

Comment: However, I'm still trying to figure out why the top corners of your imageView look rectangular, because I got all corner looks circular when trying your code. Maybe you should try setting the background color of the collectionViewCell to something else to see if the image got a white top border...? (Sorry I know that sounds silly, but I do really want to see what is the actually size of the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a containerView in your collectionViewCell, add the imageView in it (I set my image, you set your url image) and set constraints with Auto Layout like this:

```
let containerView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .red
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    v.layer.masksToBounds = true
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return v
}()
```

now set imageView and Label:

```
let dummyImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return imageView
}()

let dummyLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    label.text = "Lean Methodology"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .regular)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return label
}()
```

after that set constraints with Auto Layout

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    backgroundColor = .white
    
    contentView.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 230).isActive = true
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    
    containerView.addSubview(dummyImageView)
    dummyImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    addSubview(dummyLabel)
    dummyLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this, some views might clip the layer and extend outside of its designated frame. Usually, when cornerRadius doesn't work, I would use this extension:

```swift
extension UIImageView {
    func setRoundedEdge(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat){
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

with usage being

```swift
imageView.setRoundedEdge(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 8);
```

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Is your imageview still masked to bounds?

Comment: imageView.layoutIfNeeded()imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.setRoundedEdge(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 8);

Comment: Can you update your question with an image of the before and after?

Comment: Please see question

Comment: Try getting rid of `imageView.layoutIfNeeded()` as from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462809/how-to-get-uiimageview-size-after-autolayout-is-applied), you can see that the function changes the bounds.

Comment: Please see updated question with updated code. Still same issue.

Comment: As of right now, I have no clue what the reason is. I would suggest making sure the frame of the imageview is correct as that might be why the image is getting cut off.